# Google Cloud Function error "OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code"

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I get an error from time to time when deploying nodejs10 cloud functions to GCP.  The error seems to go away on it's own, I just redeploy the same thing a few times.  Anyone know what causes it?  He's the log:

```
command: gcloud beta functions deploy exchangeIcon --verbosity debug --runtime nodejs10 --memory 128 --region europe-west1 --timeout 5 --trigger-http --set-env-vars=FUNCTION_REGION=europe-west1,BUILD_DATE=2019-05-09T10:01:05.497Z --entry-point app

DEBUG: Running [gcloud.beta.functions.deploy] with arguments: [--entry-point: "app", --memory: "134217728", --region: "europe-west1", --runtime: "nodejs10", --set-env-vars: "OrderedDict([(u'FUNCTION_REGION', u'europe-west1'), (u'BUILD_DATE', u'2019-05-09T10:01:05.497Z')])", --timeout: "5", --trigger-http: "True", --verbosity: "debug", NAME: "exchangeIcon"]
INFO: Not using a .gcloudignore file.
INFO: Not using a .gcloudignore file.
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...
..........................................................................failed.
DEBUG: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/cli.py", line 985, in Execute
    resources = calliope_command.Run(cli=self, args=args)
  File "/Users/me/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/backend.py", line 795, in Run
    resources = command_instance.Run(args)
  File "/Users/me/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/functions/deploy.py", line 231, in Run
    enable_vpc_connector=True)
  File "/Users/me/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/surface/functions/deploy.py", line 175, in _Run
    return api_util.PatchFunction(function, updated_fields)
  File "/Users/me/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/util.py", line 300, in CatchHTTPErrorRaiseHTTPExceptionFn
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/util.py", line 356, in PatchFunction
    operations.Wait(op, messages, client, _DEPLOY_WAIT_NOTICE)
  File "/Users/me/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 126, in Wait
    _WaitForOperation(client, request, notice)
  File "/Users/me/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 101, in _WaitForOperation
    sleep_ms=SLEEP_MS)
  File "/Users/me/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/core/util/retry.py", line 219, in RetryOnResult
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/me/Downloads/google-cloud-sdk/lib/googlecloudsdk/api_lib/functions/operations.py", line 65, in _GetOperationStatus
    raise exceptions.FunctionsError(OperationErrorToString(op.error))
FunctionsError: OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: 
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code.
```

In my Stackdriver Logging I just see `INVALID_ARGUMENT`, but nothing else.

Answer (score 2):

The problem stems from your terminal commands not being properly formatted.

```
--verbosity=debug
```

is the proper way to type this. Also same thing with your runtime.